# maven surefire exclusion: Is it buggy?

Tags: maven, classnotfoundexception, surefire

Note: I've filed an official JIRA For this http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5603, as I'm pretty sure its a bug in maven.  Answers to this thread I will evaluate and update in both places, because I'm pretty sure others will run into this issue when doing exclusion filters on complex code bases.

My full pom file is here for reference: https://gist.github.com/jayunit100/9644221 (this is a version of hadoop that im playing with in the source code).

Ive found some very odd behaviour in surefire:

```
mvn test
```

With the following exclusion filter under the "excludes" tag:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <startKdc>${startKdc}</startKdc>
        <kdc.resource.dir>${kdc.resource.dir}</kdc.resource.dir>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
      <properties>
        <property>
          <name>listener</name>
          <value>org.apache.hadoop.test.TimedOutTestsListener</value>
        </property>
      </properties>
      <excludes>
      <exclude>asbdfoin</exclude>
  </excludes>
    </configuration>
```

Results in an exception like this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test 
(default-test) on project hadoop-common: Execution default-test of goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test failed: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: EmptyRequestProto; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: EmptyRequestProto -> [Help 1]
```

In otherwords: Exclusion filters can result in NoClassDefFoundError messages, when the exclusion filter doesn't match anything at all.

My question : How could the maven surefire exclusion filter cause a ClassNotFound error to manifest ?  If anything, I would expect it to REDUCE the amount of attempts to load classes, not increase them.

FYI, some color on this:  The class itself is an inner class:

```
public static final class EmptyRequestProto extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage
```

I have seen https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-988‎, and possibly its related, but I the fact that my "exclude" filter doesnt match ANY class in the code base, it might be distinct.

Comment: Please show your full pom file.

Answer (score 0):

This is my surefire configuration. I have included an exclude that definitly does not match anything. It worked for me. I could not reproduce your exception. Maybe you misconfigured it within your pom.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.16</version>
     <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>abcdefghijk</exclude>
        </excludes>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Also, does your project have static inner classes ?  The bug is triggered by static internal classes, as classnotfound exceptions.  I THINK what happens is all classes get scanned at runtime and somehow parsed, and then when they are inspected by some magic in surefire, a class load is attempted, which fails because the FQ class name is lost .  or something along those lines.  See the jira associated with this.  but thanks for testing this on a simpler system, it helps to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have inner static classes. But to be certain I have to check tomorrow.

Comment: There very definitly no static inner classes within my project. I corrected this and included some fakes into my source code and the test classes. Still surefire works.